# Expected Distance of Closer of Two Random Points to center of Unit Square

Tags: probability, expectation

Given two random points picked in the unit square, what is the expected distance from the center of the square to the closer of the two points?

The expected distance from the center of a square to a random point is known to be about 0.382597. Precisely, it is given by the universal parabolic constant over 6 (P/6). I believe I have managed to calculate an approximate answer of 0.3015435, but all methods I have tried so far to calculate a nice integral have failed.

Comment: I don't think the expected distance alone will be enough to solve this. Do you know the PDF or CDF of the distance between a random point and the center?

Comment: Yes, I do. Using order statistics and the matlab int function I was able to calculate an expected value. I guess I was hoping that there would be a more intuitive and simple way to do it, but unfortunately it looks like there is no way to get rid of that nasty integration.

Comment: yea I don't know a simpler way, maybe someone else here might, I'd be interested to see

Comment: Hm... does it even matter that there are two random points?

Comment: Yes, because those points closer to the center are more likely to be the closer point, so to speak, if two points are being chosen.

Comment: For anyone that is curious, I came up with an easier way to calculate the expected value. It is a bit complicated, but it involves an alternative equation for the expectation for a non-negative random variable (the integral of 1 - cdf). From there, using a few properties of order statistics, I have simplified the expression so that all that remains is one "nasty" integral that is definitely more manageable than all previous attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Mathematica*, we can symbolically compute the PDF of $$D_{(1)} = \min (D_1, D_2), \quad D_i \sim \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}, \\ X, Y \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1/2, 1/2)$$ with the command

```
FullSimplify[PDF[OrderDistribution[{ProbabilityDistribution[
 FullSimplify[PDF[TransformedDistribution[
    Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{-1/2, 1/2}], 
     Distributed[y, UniformDistribution[{-1/2, 1/2}]}], d], 
 0 < d < 1/Sqrt[2]], {d, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}], 2}, 1], d], 
0 < d < 1/Sqrt[2]]
```

which gives output equivalent to

$$f_{D_{(1)}}(d) = \begin{cases}
 4 \pi  d (1 - \pi  d^2) & 0 \le d\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
 4 d (\pi - 4 \tan ^{-1}t)(1 - \pi d^2 - t + 4 d^2 \tan ^{-1}t)& \frac{1}{2} < d < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{cases}$$ where $t = \sqrt{4d^2-1}$.  A plot of this function is shown below:  [image]

We can also compute an expectation but *Mathematica* gives the result in terms of polylogarithms and I did not attempt to simplify it further.  Numerical approximation gives
$$\operatorname{E}[D_{(1)}] \approx 0.30154355840431487492052719049429100813792402431564\ldots.$$

Comment: Thanks! It is good to know that using this method the expectation I had previously calculated is identical to it.